# Is it correct to use "All season product" to indicate a product can be used in every season of the year?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

Assuming an hypothetical product, would it be correct to use an description such as "Thermo-adaptable 500 thread **all season linen**" to describe it?

A small sentence indicating that the product was specially conceived for use all year long (be it during winter or summer) is needed, but I am not sure if the phrase above sounds right for native English speakers, or if there is a better way of conveying the wanted semantics.

Is this use of wording correct?
Thanks

Comment: Is 'hypothetical' one of these aspirated words that optionally takes _an_? I find 'an hotel' and 'an historical account' grating enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example sentence, "all season" is acting as an adjective that is modifying the word "linen". It will be grammatically correct if you use a hyphen. "all-season linen" is a *more* correct form.

Comment: Spelling and grammar are usually treated as separate issues on ELU, but the hyphen can certainly help disambiguate in some instances. Would you say _500 thread_ should be hyphenated?